# javascript get the current class number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this one:

```
<ul>
<li>zero</li>
<li>one</li>
<li class="current">two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li>
</ul>
```

How can I get the number of current class? (like 2).

Comment: do you want this     $("ul li.current").text();// show two

Comment: what do u want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Very Simple:

Just Use **.html()** , **.index()** , **.text()** with the selector

**Like This Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/PzWxs/5/

Here is the Code :

```
   var currentClassValue = $('li.current').html();  
      alert(currentClassValue);
```

OR

```
   var currentClassValue = $('li.current').index();  
      alert(currentClassValue);
```

OR

```
   var currentClassValue = $('li.current').text();  
      alert(currentClassValue);
```

**Use any one of the above you like :)**

Comment: i don't wnat text, i wnat only number like 1, 2, 3, 4,

Comment: Use index :) But keep in mind. Index always start from 0

Comment: please vote up too if it worked :D

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: Alright vote up when you reach 15 rep ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery then use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) which returns position of element starting from zero

`$('li.current').index()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li.current").text();// show two

$('ul li.current').index(); //show index 2
```

reference [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/)